# What is LRS List and Create Container Operations?

Tags: azure, blob

From last few days I had charging approx $0.16 everyday for "LRS List and Create Container Operations". I don't know from where request is coming, I have checked all logs and metrics.

[image]

[image]

So here request is around 35k in last few days. But I don't have any idea from where all this request are coming.

Comment: Do you have any Azure Functions which is using this storage account? Also check if logging is enabled for this storage account?

Comment: Yes I have, but its not executing I have checked that.

Comment: Is your Function still active (but not executing) or is it disabled?

Comment: Yes, function is still active.

Comment: Can you disable the Function and see if that reduces the transactions?

Comment: Thank You so much. request went to 0, can you please elaborate why that happening , why that much of requests and I have used blob trigger function, is that is not under free tier?

Comment: Basically even though your Azure Function is not running yet the Function Runtime uses the storage account and makes a number of requests. My guess is that it is polling the storage account to check for new blobs. These requests are billable.